# Elementor: a section is hidden on mobile phones

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to use OceanWp theme.
And I have imported demo data "Lawyer". And modified it for myself.

This is a demo: https://lawyer.oceanwp.org/

The section "Why Choose Our Firm" does not apper on mobile phones.
Both in the demo, and in my case.

It has switched somewhere. I have also checked if a class is added manually. It seems that no class is added. But in fact elementor-hidden-phone is still present. Could you tell me what to look at to solve the problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bug in Elementor: check "Hide On Mobile" and just uncheck it - class will disapper

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Elementor bug. You'll have to explicitly tell Elementor to 'Play On Mobile' by going to:

Style -> Background and setting Play On Mobile to 'yes'.

This will add "background_play_on_mobile":"yes" to the Elementor section element:

```
data-settings='{"background_background":"video","background_video_link":"https:\/\/vimeo.com\/12345678","background_play_on_mobile":"yes"}'
```

Refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To fix this via CSS, simply follow the below steps.

1. Once logged in, edit the "Why Choose Our Firm" section in the elementor.
2. Add a class, for example - "lawyer-firmvisible-section".
3. Put the CSS

   ```
   @media (max-width: 1024px){
     section.lawyer-firmvisible-section {
       display: block!important;
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this CSS in the custom CSS plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
     section.lawyer-firmvisible-section {
          display: block !important;
       }
    }
```

Comment: But isn't it just masking the error? Somewhere in Elementor settings are set for one behaviour of the page. But then you come and reshape it with a custom css. 

I'd prefer to find out where in elementor this erronious settings are made.